# How to achieve android constraint layout in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am looking for an equivalent of constraint layout from Android in Xamarin forms. Is there any? How can I achieve this in XAML? I have been looking around and have not found anything useful.

Thank you so much for any recommendations.

Comment: Although I don't see any good explanation of using it, I have successfully used [Constraint Expression class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.constraintexpression?view=xamarin-forms) in c# code-behind to describe both child-child constraints (aka "peer constraints") and child-parent constraints.

Answer (score 0):

In general, for my base page's layout I use a grid (but there are many ways to handle a page layout...)
Inside this grid you can put your UI elements. But what is interesting is that you can set Width x Height for each rows and columns of the grid.

Then you can also set `margin` properties for each of your UI elements.

I'm not familiar with Android design but in Xamarin Forms you can have something like that:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.5*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="0.5*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.25*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.75*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Label Text="Top Left" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5,10,5,10" />
    <Label Text="Top Right" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />
    <Label Text="Bottom Left" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" />
    <Label Text="Bottom Right" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />

</Grid>
```

This sample generates a layout with 4 parts (2 rows, 2 columns). Rows will have the same height and fill the screen. 2nd column will be 3x larger than 1st one and both will fill the screen.

**Margin="5,10,5,10"** ensure that an empty space of 5 'pixels' is always present before the label, 10 'pixels' are present on top the label ...

**There are several controls to manage layout**, like `StackLayout` or `Listview` (to manage items). If you have a more concrete example to implement, don't hesitate to complete your question.

I suggest you to check this documentation, you will find all you need !
[Xamarin Forms layout documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however the answer does not reply to my question. I already have Grid with similar layout, but I would like to achieve the same behavior as the Constraint layout does on Android. I would like to achieve exactly this behavior.